# Only axis preview is moving, object stays intact

Tags: interface, axis

Sorry for a noob question, but I really cannot not find the answer for some time now. I pressed something in Blender, and now my objects do not move / do not rotate / do not scale. All I see is just a 3d axis moving/rotating/scaling (please see the screenshot below). What did I press and how do I get back to normal?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have 'Affect only origins' checked on the Transform drop-down I've marked below:

[image]